# How to input these variables in a magento 2.3.4 mail template

Tags: email-templates, variables

We would like to display these variables in a new email template (which is currently assigned to a orderstate):

Ordernumber, Customername, Order Status & Invoicenumber.

The following code does not work:

```
{{var order.increment_id}}, {{var customer.name}}, {{trans "%name," name=$order.getCustomerName()}}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my execute function (observer) any other file code add

You can try as below:

```
$templateVars = array(
                'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore(),
                'message'   => 'We processed your order ID We will contact you soon in mail for the acknowledgement if you not receive mail within 4 hours please get help from support@xxx.com',
                'myvar2' => 'myvar2 value come here',
                'myvar3' => 'myvar3 value come here'
            );
```

In email template email_template.html, use like

```
{{var myvar2}}
{{var myvar3}}
{{trans "%customer_name" customer_name=$myvar3}}
```

Comment: How to implement this?

Comment: Please refer https://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/sending-custom-emails-using-custom-module-in-magento-2/